# How to place an Imageview on top of anothe Layout as shown in the figure?

Tags: android, layout

I would like to create a layout which could make the UI look like as shown in figure.[image]

All comments and pointers welcome.

---

Adding my current Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/video_panel">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/top_panel" android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="14" android:background="@drawable/top_bg1">

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/space" />

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/button_panel" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:id="@+id/time"
            android:text="@string/space" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="4" android:id="@+id/screen">
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_panel" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:layout_weight="13"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/bottom_bg1"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true">

        <LinearLayout android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/album_art" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="256dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"></ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/album_art"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="10dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/status_frame"
            android:id="@+id/info_panel">
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/status_frame" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:visibility="visible" android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:paddingTop="50dip">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/status" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

How Should i change this layout to make it look like in my picture?

Answer (score 2):

How about changing the framelayout to a relativelayout.

Have the VideoView fill_parent, the bluelayout align_parentBottom=true, the linearlayout horizontallayout center horizontal, alignparentbottom, the blue image view align_parentleft=true, alignparentbottom true, with a large bottom margin to bump it up. the orange imageview alignparentright & bottom.

Answer (score 1):

There is several possibilities but I guess I would go for a simple negative top margin on the imageview. Put the image view in your blue linearview and `android:layout_marginTop="-20dip"`.

This should work

Comment: In your layout make the blue group a linearview with a horizontal orientation. Then inside it as direct children put your imageview, your linearlayout and your other imageview. Then when applying the negative margin it should work.

Comment: I have a similar situation with a vertical linear layout. Need to shift an ImageView, which is a direct child, a bit to the left. What happens: The View is shifted indeed (can see it with android layout manager) but the drawable keeps in the same place. Besides the drawable doesn't go to the left, it's also cut on the right side because the ImageView is shifted to the left.

Comment: Sorry ixx, what you describe is weird. If you did not resolve it yet, open a new question and post your code. There maybe something wrong with it.